# aws security groups in pulumi with inline rules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I'm trying to create security groups in pulumi with inline rules, specifically rules that reference another security group as a source. None of these group exist yet and need to be created in a loop from a variable as there may be quite a lot of them.

Here's a example of what the variables looks like:

```
compute:security_groups:
- name: load-balancer
  inbound:
  - cidr_blocks: null
    from_port: 80
    protocol: tcp
    source_security_group: cache
    to_port: 80
  - cidr_blocks: null
    from_port: 22
    protocol: tcp
    source_security_group: logging
    to_port: 22
- name: cache
  inbound:
  - cidr_blocks: null
    from_port: 6379
    protocol: tcp
    source_security_group: load-balancer
    to_port: 6379
- name: logging
  inbound:
  - cidr_blocks: null
    from_port: 22
    protocol: tcp
    source_security_group: cache
    to_port: 22
  - cidr_blocks: null
    from_port: 5044
    protocol: tcp
    source_security_group: load-balancer
    to_port: 5044
```

We should create a security group called `name` and include an inline rule for each item under `inbound`. The source security group needs to to point back to the group referenced in `source_security_group`

The closest I've gotten is to create the rules first with as a `SecurityGroupIngressArgs` then add them to a seperatly created group. Something like:

```
env_name = pulumi.get_stack()
default_tags = {'resource-group': env_name, 'environment': env_name, 'managed-by': "pulumi"}


### Securty groups
# Create groups
sg_list = []
for sg in config.require_object('security_groups'):

    # create rules
    inbound_list = []
    for item in sg['inbound']:
        source_group_name = env_name + '-' + item['source_security_group']
        inbound_list.append(aws.ec2.SecurityGroupIngressArgs(
            from_port   = item['from_port'],
            to_port     = item['to_port'],
            protocol    = item['protocol'],
            security_groups = sg_list[source_group_name.id]
        ))

    # create groups
    sg_name = env_name + '-' + sg.get('name')
    sg_list.append(aws.ec2.SecurityGroup(sg_name,
        description = sg.get('description'),
        vpc_id      = kv_vpc['id'],
        ingress     = inbound_list,
        egress      = outbound_list,
        tags        = {**default_tags,**{'Name': sg_name}}
        )
    )
```

This approach work fine for cidr blocks but with security groups as the source I can't reference  security group id's that have not been created yet. I'm not sure how to structure this with pulumi.

Comment: Is the error happening in the code above or is that a smaller part of a much larger file?

Comment: It's a smaller part of a larger file. However this is more of a 'how do I approach this' question, rather then a specific error. I don't how how to handle `security_groups` in pulumi in this senario.

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to remember is that when you're writing this, and when it's running some of the resources won't have been created yet (either because it takes a while for AWS to create things or because it hasn't got to that bit in the code yet).

Pulumi handles this by using what we call ["inputs" and "outputs"](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#outputs) (if you know javascript/typescript then you'll know what I mean by a promise), and more specifically you'll want to look at the [apply](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#apply) example where it uses a lambda to get the variables.

In some cases you'll be able to use the array of security groups directly. Here's an example in the docs:

```
import pulumi
import pulumi_aws as aws

size = 't2.micro'
ami = aws.get_ami(most_recent="true",
              owners=["137112412989"],
              filters=[{"name":"name","values":["amzn-ami-hvm-*"]}])

group = aws.ec2.SecurityGroup('webserver-secgrp',
    description='Enable HTTP access',
    ingress=[
        { 'protocol': 'tcp', 'from_port': 22, 'to_port': 22, 'cidr_blocks': ['0.0.0.0/0'] }
    ])

server = aws.ec2.Instance('webserver-www',
    instance_type=size,
    vpc_security_group_ids=[group.id], # reference security group from above
    ami=ami.id)

pulumi.export('publicIp', server.public_ip)
pulumi.export('publicHostName', server.public_dns)
```

([link to example in docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/tutorials/aws/ec2-webserver/#step-2-create-an-ec2-instance-with-ssh-access))

Answer (score 0):

Create a security group rule resource after creating all security group and associate the rule to required security group.

```
sg_1 = aws.ec2.SecurityGroup(
     'sg1',
      description='Security group',                                     
)

sg_2 = aws.ec2.SecurityGroup(
     'sg2',
      description='Security group',
      ingress=[
        {'protocol': 'tcp',
        'description': "allow http access from sg1",
        'from_port': 8080,
        'to_port': 8080,
        'security_groups': [sg_1.id]
        }
      ]                                       
     )

sg1_rule = aws.ec2.SecurityGroupRule(
     "allow-s2",
     type="ingress",
     description= "allow http access from sg2"
     protocol="tcp",
     to_port= 8080,
     from_port= 8080,
     security_group_id=sg_1.id,
     source_security_group_id=vsg_2.id
    )
```